# createRoot(...): Target container is not a DOM element. (When using Jest and React testing Library)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-dom

Please I need help to get ride of this error, I am trying to create a test for my App component where I make sure that the initialeTimes() function works as expected and returns the object mentioned bellow.

However when I do run the test it gives me the following error:

```
createRoot(...): Target container is not a DOM element .import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom" 
   6 |
>  7 | const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
     |                       ^
   8 | root.render(
   9 |   <React.StrictMode>
  10 |     <BrowserRouter>.
```

Here is the code for App.js:

```
import {React, useReducer} from 'react';
import {Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom"
import './App.css';
import BookingPage from './components/BookingPage';
import Home from './components/Home';

function updateTimes(availableTimes, action)
{
  switch(action.type)
  {
    case 'SET_DATE':
        return {...availableTimes, select: action.payload};
    default:
      return availableTimes;
  }
}

export function  initializeTimes()
{
  return {select : null};
}


const App = ()  =>{
  const [availableTimes, dispatch] = useReducer(updateTimes, initializeTimes);

  return (
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/booking" element={<BookingPage availableTimes={availableTimes} dispatch={dispatch} />} />
    </Routes>
  ) 
}

export default App;
```

And this is the test :

```
// App.test.js
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { initializeTimes } from '../App'; 

test('initializeTimes returns the expected object', () => {
    const res = initializeTimes()
    expect(res).toEqual({ select: null });
});
```

I also tried:

```
// App.test.js
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import App, { initializeTimes } from '../App';

test('initializeTimes returns the expected object', () => {
    render(<App/>)
    const res = initializeTimes()
    expect(res).toEqual({ select: null });
});
```

I updated and installed jest manually but the problem continues to happen. I would appreaciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

The first testing code block is fine, it should work.

Do you have other test files in your project environment? Ones which are calling 'render' on React components? The first code block isn't even making any calls to render a React component so no error should be thrown in that regard if this is the only test file you have.

If this is the only test file, are you sure you have initialized React correctly? - You didn't show your file where the root is created.

Comment: ```import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom" 

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <App/>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);```


This is the root file for my project , what is really weird is that all the snippets that i shared throw the same error, while the other tests I have are passed successfully.